# JABX, создание файла и запись XML, Java

Tags: java, xml

Изучаю JABX, написал маленький парсер, который вытягивает и сохраняет все в XML. Но столкнулся с проблемой, не могу добавить атрибут во вложенный элемент. Пытался создать еще один класс Param, но не смог всунуть его в элемент `<offers>`
Вот `param name=` нужно добавить, что бы получилось как-то так:

```
<offers>
<offer available="true">
<categoryId>18069925</categoryId>
<name>testNameProduct1</name>
<param name="Состояние">Новое</param>
<param name="Цвет">Черный</param>
<param name="Вес">43<param>
</offer>
</offers>
```

Максимум, что получалось, это

```
<offers>
<offer available="true">
<categoryId>18069925</categoryId>
<name>testNameProduct1</name>
<param>Новое</param>
</offer>
</offers>
```

Части кода:

```
 Offers list = new Offers();
 for (int j = 0; j < 40; j++) {
            list.add(parseProduct(j, productLinks.get(j).toString()));
        }
```

метод:

```
 public static Offer parseProduct(int j, String str) {
 Offer offer = new Offer();
 offer.setName(name);
 offer.setChildrenAllowed(true);
 offer.setCategoryId(CategoryId);
 return offer;
 }
```

Класс Offers

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "offers")
public class Offers {
List<Offer> offers;

@XmlElement(name = "offer")
public void setOffers(List<Offer> offers) {
    this.offers = offers;
}

public List<Offer> getOffers() {
    return offers;
}

public void add(Offer offer) {
    if (this.offers == null) {
        this.offers = new ArrayList<Offer>();
    }
    this.offers.add(offer);


}
}
```

Класс Offer

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "offer")
public class Offer {
String name;
int categoryId;


@XmlElement(name = "name")
public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

Boolean available;

@XmlAttribute(name = "available")
public void setChildrenAllowed(Boolean childrenAllowed) {
    this.available = childrenAllowed;
}

@XmlElement(name = "categoryId")
public void setCategoryId(int categoryId) {
    this.categoryId = categoryId;
}


public int getCategoryId() {
    return categoryId;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public Boolean getChildrenAllowed() {
    return available;
}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

в класс `Offer` нужно добавить новый объект `Param`

```
public class Param
{
    private String content;
    private String name;

    public String getContent ()
    {
        return content;
    }

    public void setContent (String content)
    {
        this.content = content;
    }

    public String getName ()
    {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName (String name)
    {
        this.name = name;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString()
    {
        return "ClassPojo [content = "+content+", name = "+name+"]";
    }
}


public class Offer
{
    private Param[] param;
    private String categoryId;
    private String name;

    public Param[] getParam ()
    {
        return param;
    }

    public void setParam (Param[] param)
    {
        this.param = param;
    }
............
}
```

Comment: Спасибо, сейчас получается вот так:        <param>
            <name>Новое</name>
        </param>

Comment: Вернее уже даже к такому виду пришел `<param name="Состояние">
            <content>Новое</content>
        </param>` убрать бы  <conten> и было бы вообще супер =)

Comment: Спасибо, помогло @XmlValue

Comment: всегда пожалуйста